# How To take screenshot in selenium webdriver with stepdefinition name & time

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, screenshot

I'm new to selenium .Please help me with how to take screenshot in seleniumwebdriver using java with filename as stepdefinition & time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific method to note the stepname,you will have to explicitly mention the stepname.
To get the time you can use the Date Class

**Steps to get the screenshot:**

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    /* Taking the screenshot */
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    /* Saving the screenshot file, 
      over here you can name the file as per your wish ex: step_Desc_dd-mm-yy */
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

**Steps to get the Date:**

```
public String get_Curr_Date()
{
    /* DateFormat you define the format ex: 17-12-16 03-59 */
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YY hh-mm");

    /* Getting the current date & time */
    Date date = new Date();

    /* Storing the date & time in a string in previously mentioned format */
    String dateTime = dateFormat.format(date);

    return dateTime ;
}
```